# MYSQL how to merge rows with same field id into a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

I have a select statement with rows as
[table_Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hwia.png)

```
rowid | title                     | author_f_name | author_m_name | author_l_name| coauthor_first_name | coauthor_middle_name | coauthor_last_name
1.   "Blog Title.       Roy                  NULL                   Thomas.               Joe                   Shann               Mathews
1.   "Blog Title.       Thomas                  NULL              Edison            Kunal               NULL                       Shar
```

I need to merge the rows such that blogs with same row id are merged into a single row.
I am trying to get either `<author fname, author mname, author lname | coauthor fname coauthor lname>` or a column as author co author
Each blog can have multiple authors and co authors as an example
Blog1 has Thomas Edison, Dan Mathre, Robert Cook as authors and Joe Randall as co author.

I tried

```
CONCAT_WS('|', group_concat(concat(ifnull(people.prefix, ' '), ' ' ,ifnull(people.first_name, ' '), ' ' ,ifnull(people.middle_name, ' '), ' ' ,ifnull(people.last_name, ' '), '|', ifnull(peopleData.prefix, ' '), ' ' ,ifnull(peopleData.first_name, ' '), ' ' ,ifnull(peopleData.middle_name, ' '), ' ' ,ifnull(peopleData.last_name, ' '))) ) 
             AS authors
```

which should ideally return author names and co author names separated by |||.

However there are multiple iterations here as in

```
Roy Thomas | Joe Shan, Roy Thomas | Kunal Shar, Thomas Edison | Joe Shan, Thomas Edison | Kunal Shar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT supports `DISTINCT` and SEPARATOR``

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `rowid` VARCHAR(139),
>   `title` VARCHAR(139),
>   `author_f_name` VARCHAR(139),
>   `author_m_name` VARCHAR(139),
>   `author_l_name` VARCHAR(139),
>   `coauthor_first_name` VARCHAR(139),
>   `coauthor_middle_name` VARCHAR(139),
>   `coauthor_last_name` VARCHAR(139)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`rowid`, `title`, `author_f_name`, `author_m_name`, `author_l_name`, `coauthor_first_name`, `coauthor_middle_name`, `coauthor_last_name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1.',   'Blog Title.',       'Roy',                  NULL,                   'Thomas.',               'Joe',                   'Shann',               'Mathews'),
>   ('1.',   'Blog Title.',       'Thomas',                  'NULL',              'Edison',            'Kunal',               NULL,                       'Shar');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> `rowid`
> , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `title`  SEPARATOR ' |||') tilte
> , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `author_f_name` SEPARATOR ' |||') author_f_name
> , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `author_m_name` SEPARATOR ' |||') author_m_name
> , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `author_l_name` SEPARATOR ' |||') author_l_name
> , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `coauthor_first_name` SEPARATOR ' |||') coauthor_first_name
> , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `coauthor_middle_name` SEPARATOR ' |||') coauthor_middle_name
> , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `coauthor_last_name` SEPARATOR ' |||') coauthor_last_name
> FROM table1
> GROUP BY `rowid`
> ```
>
> ```
> rowid | tilte       | author_f_name | author_m_name | author_l_name     | coauthor_first_name | coauthor_middle_name | coauthor_last_name
> :---- | :---------- | :------------ | :------------ | :---------------- | :------------------ | :------------------- | :-----------------
> 1.    | Blog Title. | Roy |||Thomas | NULL          | Edison |||Thomas. | Joe |||Kunal        | Shann                | Mathews |||Shar
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dac3bf4fbc402de82d7521401e99083b)*

> ```
> SELECT 
> `rowid`
> , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `title`  SEPARATOR ' |||') tilte
> , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(`author_f_name`,' ',COALESCE(`author_m_name`,''),' ',`author_l_name`) SEPARATOR ' |||') author_full_name
> , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(`coauthor_first_name`,' ',COALESCE(`coauthor_middle_name`,''),' ',`coauthor_last_name`) SEPARATOR ' |||') coauthor_full_name
> FROM table1
> GROUP BY `rowid`
> ```
>
> ```
> rowid | tilte       | author_full_name                   | coauthor_full_name              
> :---- | :---------- | :--------------------------------- | :-------------------------------
> 1.    | Blog Title. | Roy  Thomas. |||Thomas NULL Edison | Joe Shann Mathews |||Kunal  Shar
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b823bf3115e680474f567beb444a2c1f)*

Comment: And if you want to skip NULL values - you should `COALESCE` them to empty strings.

Comment: I am trying to find a way so that I can show authors and co authors. Notice in the co_author_middle name has only Shann so would the best way to get a single author name be like mapping each Joe > Shan Kunal > Null using split. Is there a better way ?

Comment: can you add a sample output, i can't follow you

Comment: the result that you showed is exactly what I want. The end result that I want to send from my api is to get authors: Roy  Thomas, Thomas Edison and co authors Joe Shan Mathews and Kunal Shar. Here the authors are split differently and I cant figure out a way to parse them.

Comment: @LeoBabyJacob see the second query this should lead you